# How to add a background image to string?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple jokes app. Basically I've used strings to hold each and every joke. So I press joke in the app, and it gives me a joke, then I press back, and the I press joke again and it gives me joke #2 and so on. My problem is all the jokes come with a white background. I've tried using `android:background` in all my **xml** layout files but I still get a white background. I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm using strings to display the jokes. This is my the code I'm using for the jokes in my `.java` class :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void randomJoke (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); 
    //Random rand = new Random();
    //int lowerBound = 1, upperBound = 10;
    //int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(upperBound - lowerBound + 1) + lowerBound;
    //String jokeNumber = "joke" + String.valueOf(randomNumber);
    //String mess = getResources().getString(getStringResourcePath(getApplicationContext(),jokeNumber));
    String jokeNumber = "joke" + String.valueOf(iteration);
    iteration += 1;
    String mess = getResources().getString(getStringResourcePath(getApplicationContext(), jokeNumber));
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, mess);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public int getStringResourcePath(Context context, String name) {
    int joke = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", "com.primarycode.punnyjokes");
    return joke;
}
}
```

Comment: can u share activity XML layout?

Comment: can you please elaborate the question ? and where exactly do you use setText ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you might be using `TextView` to show joke in `DisplayMessageActivity`. You can achieve this as follows:

In the XML layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/myResouce"
```

or pragmatically in `onCreate()` as follows:

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myResouce);
```

---

If you want to use color, use as follows in layout XML:

```
android:background="#eee"
```